# how to integrate API with HTML in django template?

Tags: django

I am using both POST and GET method through python requests to fetch datas and submit data in an API.

```
class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def post(self,request):
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        print(email)

        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print(password)
        API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        API_URL = 'http://dev.com/rest/storeLogin'
        parameter = {
            'authToken':API_KEY,
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
        }
        r = session.post(url = API_URL, params=parameter)
        print(r.json()['code'])
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

With this above views.py class method i'm trying to post data.and I have an readymade HTML form for login ready.

```
<form class="my-login-form" action="/login" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="field-wrap">
<input type="email" name="email" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email Id"/>
</div>
<div class="field-wrap">
<input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
</div>
<button class="button button-block"/>Login</button>
<div class="forgot"><a class="user-form-toggle" href="#forgot">Forgot Password?</a></div>
</form>
```

So my dilemma is how to map both class based view and html form. Right now it seems html form is stand alone!

Answer (score -1):

You should check djangorestframework. It's a good framework for defining REST APIs with multiple formats, filters, etc, by doing mostly configuration instead of code.